# Facebook Developers Error 500

Tags: facebook

When I go to app settings (basic) and I try to add platorm (android) and I set everything correct way, I press save changes.. This button goes to disabled mode for like 4 seconds and then I can press it again.. In console I get error 500 and changes are not saved - I cant add android platform.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somehow happends only when I use package name that is already on google play.. If I use some random, I can save it. I think we can say its just Facebook bug.